# getProcedures and getFunctions return the same ResultSet

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, resultset

I am trying to drop all the functions and procedures in my DB through java.
My current code is like so:

```
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = getConnectionToDB();
        String itemName;
        ResultSet rs = getResultSetForItem(item);
        String upperCaseItem = item.toUpperCase();
        while (rs.next()) {
            itemName = rs.getString(upperCaseItem + "_NAME");
            // Procedure and function names come with a grouping ID, remove it
            if (item.equals("procedure") || item.equals("function"))
                itemName = itemName.substring(0, itemName.indexOf(";"));
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query + " " + itemName);
        }
```

Where item is once "function" and once "procedure". Also, the query variable is set correctly to be "DROP FUNCTION" or "DROP PROCEDURE" respective to the execution.

The method of getResuletSetForItem:

```
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = getConnectionToDB();
        DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
        switch (item.toLowerCase()){
            case "function":
                rs = md.getFunctions("LDMS", "dbo", "%");
                break;
            case "procedure":
                rs = md.getProcedures("LDMS", "dbo", "%");
                break;
        }
        return rs;
```

What happens is, I get the resultset as functions or procedures according to what I am asking for. BUT it returns also the records for the other kind (Meaning, if I asked for a ResultSet of functions, I also get the procedures as well).

This of course causes an exception when I try to, for example, execute "DROP FUNCTION X" where X is actually a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Although you don't explictly say so, it looks like you might be using the MS SQL Server driver for Java.

From the documentation it looks like the [`getFunctions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/getprocedures-method-sqlserverdatabasemetadata) and [`getProcedures`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/getprocedures-method-sqlserverdatabasemetadata) methods both return a list of functions and procedures. You need to evaluate the `FUNCTION_TYPE` column to determine which is which.

> The type of the function. It can be one of the following values:
>
> SQL_PT_UNKNOWN (0)
>
> SQL_PT_PROCEDURE (1)
>
> SQL_PT_FUNCTION (2)